# How to run ubuntu in windows 7 like a app?

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

I want to start using ubuntu for programming purpose.

Before I download it,I want to make sure that I can run it without removing windows 7.

Which version I should use?

Can I use it without partitioning my drives???

Answer (score 2):

1. open turn on/off features
2. and enable subsystem for Linux and virtual machine platform
3. click on OK
4. open powershell and type wsl --install
   and wsl --set-default-version 2 then press enter
5. type exit
6. open Microsoft store and search for Ubuntu then click on the first result
7. then click on install/get this app
8. then open the installed app
9. wait for few minutes and it will be installed
10. after that type the new user and password
11. type sudo apt-get update
    and sudo apt install xfce4 -y
    then press enter
12. install VcXsrv app from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/
13. and then type cat /etc/resolv.conf
    this command in the Ubuntu app
14. copy the ip
15. type nano ~/.bashrc
16. in the bottom type
    export DISPLAY=:0
    replace the  with the ip address
17. press ctrl+x and y
    press enter
    18 type source ~/.bashrc
    19 run the VcXsrv app
18. complete the wizard
19. in additional parameters add
    -ac
20. save the configuration and click on finish
21. type startxfce4
    in Ubuntu app to start the Ubuntu desktop
22. if we go back to our VcXsrv app
    you will see the Ubuntu desktop

All Done :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run Ubuntu like an application, you could set up a virtual machine. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox for information about how to do it. But I recommend just installing Ubuntu as a second operating system, so you'll have a dual-boot system. That's more useful and possibly easier.

Comment: That is not the point ... I totally understand the desire to run Ubuntu in a Windows virtual machine as Ubuntu (at least the 18.04) has proven a pain in the ass to configure a simple desktop sharing; so much that I have my laptop dual boot at home but cannot get myself to boot Ubuntu because I can't make it work such I see the desktop from my Windows computer at work, so... there....

Answer (score 1):

yes,you can use ubuntu without partitioning the drives through [`virtualbox`](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [`vmware`](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads) softwares.

Answer (score 1):

Best of all for complete and satisfying experience, download ubuntu iso file and ubuntu wubi installer to a same folder. Then execute wubi.exe.

It will install Ubuntu as an application in your Windows 7 and whenever you want to uninstall ubuntu, you can do it the same way you would uninstall any application from windows. Or you would again run the same wubi.exe and this time it will uninstall Ubuntu.

You can install Ubuntu using VirtualBox as mentioned in above answers but it will be hard on your resources( hardware).

For more info try the below link...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: I saw the screenshot for Windows 7 vs Ubuntu. Does it change the bootloader on the C: drive? Or is that screenshot from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way to get started.**

1. Download VirtualPlayer from [here](http://filehippo.com/download_vmware_player) and install it.
2. Download Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
3. Start Up Virtual Player. Click create new virtual machine. Then click the Ubuntu ISO that you downloaded. Follow the steps, give it maybe 10GB of space, it will only take up as much space as it's currently using even if you allow it to have 10GB, so it will probably be 5GB.
4. After following these steps you can start virtual player and it will be like running Ubuntu as an application in Windows.

---

In the future if you want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, which is nicer since there is probably less lag, you get better performance download and use Wubi. Note this doesn't need a flash drive or anything to work, just download wubi and Ubuntu and follow the steps.

Bonus:

> If you feel like your an advanced computer user the best app around to make a bootable flash drive for Linux is Unetbootin (search Google for it). This will allow you to dual boot as Wubi but has some slight advantages that you may not notice. Wubi still connects the Linux install partially to your windows install.

Comment: Is WUBI still reliable as of 14.10? I thought they were planning phasing it out a while back and that what was left of it was not likely to work. http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2014/10/wubi-for-ubuntu-1410-doesnt-work.html

Comment: Wubi is still sort of supported: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards

Comment: @amanthethy Wubi is very very unstable and buggy - it's not recommended due to lack of UEFI support and incompatibility with Windows 8 and such, so virtualizing is a better solution